# grocery crud file upload field pick file from server

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm developing a web site with `codeigniter` + `grocery crud`.

I really like the upload file feature from grocery crud.

But I'm wondering if it's possible to pick a file from a server folder instead of uploading it. I mean just put the name of the file in the field.

I don't want to write more than what is needed.

**Edit:** I want the user to be able to do both: upload a file, or pick it from a server folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've been asking myself the same question. I was thinking in doing it like this:
1 - Create a Media Library table (Wordpress style) and store all the file uploads in a table.
2 - Add a relation field to select images form this table.
http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/set_a_relation

The basic relation field will generate a select that allows you to select images by name, id, description, etc.
This is not very user friendly, so I guess you'll have to write one or two callback functions to show the users the image they are selecting

this is the approach I'll be using on my next codeigniter+grocerycrud project :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Alfonso for your answer, but as you say it's not really user friendly. I want the user to be able to do both: upload a file, or pick it from a server folder.